# Postgresql on conflict throws error

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to insert rows when target table doesn't match with stage. 
I used the following code which seems correct but I am getting error as:

> missing FROM-clause entry for table "S"

```
INSERT INTO app.CUSTOMERS(NAME, ADDRESS)
SELECT NAME, ADDRESS 
FROM STAGE.STG_CUSTOMERS S
ON CONFLICT (NAME) do update
SET NAME = S.NAME
AND ADDRESS = S.ADDRESS;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `excluded` as the table alias in the `do update` section, as follows:

```
INSERT INTO app.CUSTOMERS(NAME, ADDRESS)
SELECT NAME, ADDRESS 
FROM STAGE.STG_CUSTOMERS S
ON CONFLICT (NAME) do update
SET NAME = EXCLUDED.NAME
AND ADDRESS = EXCLUDED.ADDRESS;
```

Comment: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type character varying

Comment: Then add a unique (or primary key) or exclusion constraint on `name`.

Comment: combination of NAME, ADDRESS forms unique constraint.

Comment: Then you need to use `on conflict (name, address) do update`.

Comment: still getting same error:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

Comment: Can you please update your question with the output from `\d stage.stg_customers`.